# Show disabled toolbar icons as faded, not simple gray

Tags: winapi

WinAPI/C++ created toolbar. I see buttons are grey if disabled.

[image]

Any way to show them not simple grey, but faded to grey (like greyscale)?
New icons are needed or simple int flag to pass to api?

Comment: The Win32 toolbar control allows you to have a separate imagelist for disabled buttons. Lookup: `TB_SETDISABLEDIMAGELIST`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Win32 toolbar control allows you to have a separate imagelist for disabled buttons.
Lookup: `TB_SETDISABLEDIMAGELIST`